# JPA entity with extra supportive View

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Given table schema as below (this is mysql syntax, but does not matter)

```sql
-- base table keeping all subscription data
CREATE TABLE user_subscription (
  id         INTEGER       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id    INTEGER       NOT NULL,
  data       VARCHAR(2000) NULL,
  created_at DATETIME      NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at DATETIME      NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

-- supportive view focusing on every user's latest row
CREATE VIEW user_subscription_latest AS
  SELECT s1.*
  FROM user_subscription s1
  LEFT JOIN user_subscription s2
    ON s2.user_id = s1.user_id AND s2.updated_at > s1.updated_at
  WHERE s2.id IS NULL;
```

And I have following entity class for base table `user_subscription`

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_subscription")
public class UserSubscription implements java.io.Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
  private Integer userId;

  @Column(name = "data", nullable = true, length = 2000)
  private String data;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private java.time.LocalDateTime createdAt;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private java.time.LocalDateTime updatedAt;

}
```

And following Spring Data JPA repository (still does not matter. it can be any JPA scenario)

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

public interface UserSubscriptionRepository extends JpaRepository<UserSubscription, Integer> {

  // TODO How can I achieve this without using nativeQuery?
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user_subscription_latest", nativeQuery = true)
  java.util.List<UserSubscription> findLatest();

}
```

Since view `user_subscription_latest` is subset of `user_subscription`, they are interchangeable, but I have no idea how to put them together.

My question is what is the correct/preferred way to design the JPA entity so that I can take advantage of supportive view `user_subscription_latest` on query while keeping accessibility to base table `user_subscription`, without nativeQuery?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question on what is the recommended way (other than using a nativeQuery) to gain accessibility to your view as well as maintain your existing accessibility to the user table, the best possibility is to create another entity something like the one below,

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Immutable
public class UserSubscriptionLatest implements java.io.Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
  private Integer userId;

  @Column(name = "data", nullable = true, length = 2000)
  private String data;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private java.time.LocalDateTime createdAt;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private java.time.LocalDateTime updatedAt;

}
```

Making your entity class immutable is the most important step to working with database views in Spring Data JPA. Based on this mapping, Hibernate will ensure that your application doesn’t perform any write operations on the view. To make your persistence layer easier to use, you should take this one step further and also exclude all methods from your repository that persist, update or remove an entity.

Then create a readOnlyRepository defining an interface that extends the Repository interface and copying a few method definitions from Spring Data JPA’s standard repositories like the one below

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ReadOnlyRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {
 
    List<T> findAll();
 
    List<T> findAll(Sort sort);
 
    Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
 
    Optional<T> findById(ID id);
     
    long count();
}
```

Then create your JPArepository by extending the readOnlyRepository that we just created, this ensures that your repository is accessible for readOnly purposes and also tells the hibernate to eschew any checks pertaining to write/update

```
public interface UserSubscriptionLatestRepository extends  ReadOnlyRepository<UserSubscriptionLatest, Integer> {    
List<UserSubscriptionLatest> findById();
}
```

Hope I had answered your question

Comment: But I want to keep them interchangeable since the view is just a subset of table without transformation. With new entity I can query on the view, however JPA treat them differently and I can't persistent ViewEntity with TableRepository.

Comment: Yes I can declare relation between entities and persist them by copying to other, but the synchronization (in cache) become problematic and I'm seeking something more elegant.

Comment: I am afraid that you wont be able to persist a ViewEntity as such since views are just relations on top of actual tables. So if you want your data in the view be changed you should actually update the table instead. Atleast from what i know i dont see a possibility for you to update a view directly and want your actual tables have a different value. I get your point that you dont want to every time refresh the entity and retrieve the records, but even if the elegant solution would also do the same thing. Its not like queries will be reduced if you have everything happening in one-go.